# MySqlQuery taking too long time to execute

Tags: java, mysql

I have Four Schema in MySQL. Each Schema contains multiple tables. I have around 50000 records in all Schema. When I execute insert or update query it's taking me around 2 minutes 30 seconds to execute.
I tried the following ways

1. query cache disabled
2. Increased buffer size approximate 5 GB
3. default lock timeout

My server RAM is 8 GB

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It probably depends on your query. Too bad we don't know what it is.

Comment: Please show the query that is causing the issue.